# React on no movement for longer time

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

I would like to react on the situation, that an Android Smartphone didn't move for a longer time. For this, I created a Service, that implements SensorEventListener.

How can I reach, that the Service does something, if the Smartphone didn't move since, for example, 10 minutes? How can I decide, if the changes were significant or not? How about fail measurements? Any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        if (changes are significant) {
            lastChangesTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            values = event.values;
        } else if (changes are not significant and last significant changes were 10 minutes ago) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i saw a `TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION` in android sensor https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html have you tried listenning to this sensor event? And wait  10 min if it's not trigered you have your "no mouvement event"

Comment: ok i tryed it and it need a VERY significant move to proceed so it might not be what you are looking for ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/TriggerEventListener.html ) Can you give me an exemple of "significant move"?

Comment: Yes, i already tried the SIGNIFICANT_MOTION. And yes, Google and me, we have different interpretations of "significant". The second problem is, that I have to develop for API 16. A significant move in my case is every action, you are doing with your smartphone. Pick up the the phone from the desk or writing a message.